# How do you use python to recognize two objects that are the same in a graph?

Tags: opencv

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here are two pairs of pictures, how to use python to identify the position of objects in the small picture in the big picture, such as the first apple and the second pentagram, can you give me some advice or ideas? Thank you

So my current idea is to figure out where all the objects in this big picture are

And then find out where the object is in the little diagram

And then I'm going to use the objects in the smaller picture to find the positions in the larger picture

So here's the problem

1. How to find out the position of objects in the graph
2. How to scale the image due to the different pixels of the image

Comment: [`cv2.matchTemplate()`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html)

Comment: @ZdaR Thank you for your advice. I used it, but the result was not correct

Comment: Can you please elaborate by editing your question as what is the code you are trying and how is it not working.

Comment: @ZdaR I have only one idea at present, but I don't know what algorithm or tool to use to realize my idea.. My ideas have been updated in the question